# generic get-method for hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, generics, get

I'm trying to get a generic get-method to load an object from database by a certain id with hibernate. Before i started the method had looked like:

```
public static Object getObjectFromDatabase(Class c, long id) {
    Transaction newTransaction = getSession().beginTransaction();
    Object result = getSession().get(c, id);

    newTransaction.commit();


    return result;
}
```

Then i tried to get the method generic by using the following code:

```
public static <T> T getObjectFromDatabase(Class<T> c, long id) {
    Transaction newTransaction = getSession().beginTransaction();
    T result = getSession().get(c, id);

    newTransaction.commit();


    return result;
}
```

Unfortunately the line

```
   T result = getSession().get(c, id);
```

gives out an error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to T

I know that i could just use an explicit cast to T

```
   T result = (T) getSession().get(c, id);
```

But is there a way to avoid this cast??

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No - the `get(Class, Serializable)` method in `Session` is only declared to return `Object`. It's not a generic method itself, which is why you need to do the cast in some way or other.

You could make the cast safer using the [`Class.cast`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#cast%28java.lang.Object%29) method though:

```
T result = c.cast(getSession().get(c, id));
```

That will do a properly checked cast at execution time, rather than just doing a "pretend" cast which doesn't really do anything.

Comment: Is there a reason for that? The only thing that comes to my mind is that Hibernate was created before the introduction of Generics in Java. But they still could've added the functionality.

Comment: @h4nek: I don't know, I'm afraid.